# When merging two dataframs column changes from dtype='datetime64[ns]' to dtype: object, how to avoid?

Tags: python-3.x

I use colab for Python. Sorry for the inconvenience on picture representation instead of dataframes.

df2 when merged with df12, df12 column name change from `dtypes = datetime64[ns] to dtype: object`, how to avoid?

```
print(df12)
df12.columns

print(df2.head(10))
df2.index.name = 'Stock'
print(df2.index)

print(df12.head(10))
df12.index.name = 'Stock'
print(df12.index)

df13 = df2.merge(df12, on='Stock')
print(df13.head(10))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try this df13 = df2.astype(dtype).merge(df12.astype(dtype), on-'Stock')

Comment: does not work. It changes all the rows to datetime64[ns]